# asp.net mvc Type.GetMethod when two action with same name, but get and post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, get

in asp.net mvc 4, I write a custom Exception handler, working as a Attribute named HandleCustomError.

In this handler, I should know which action the current request for,  then I can know what kind of return type for this action. I will return different data for "return type view() and json".

But, now I have two action with the same name, but one is for "Get", other is for "Post".The method "GetMethod" return an error: " System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException "

```
public class HandleCustomError : System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //base.OnException(filterContext);
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //Determine the return type of the action
            string actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            Type controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
            var method = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var returnType = method.ReturnType;
        }
        ....(Omitted)
```

Comment: show your both actions

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this issue that below line was giving Ambigeous issue

> controllerType.GetMethod(actionName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase |
>   BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

Reason was that controller has two method with same name one is

> [HTTPGET]

and other iis

> [HTTPPOST]

.

For to get exact method I use GetMethods and LINQ. 
Note: In controller writting **[HTTPGet]**on action is not compulsory for get method i.e. on action if HTTpGet is not written the by default .net will consider it as **[HttpGet]**. But for post action it is compulsory. 
Will use this property for finding the correct method.

**Steps**
1. Find Type of request
2. Find the action using reflection

1. Finding Request type:

> var actionName =
>   filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
>      Type typeOfRequest = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestType.ToLower()
>   =="get"?typeof(HttpGetAttribute):typeof(HttpPostAttribute);

2. Finding method:

> ```
> var cntMethods = controllerType.GetMethods()
>                  .Where(m => 
>                     m.Name == actionName &&
>                     (  (  typeOfRequest == typeof(HttpPostAttribute) && 
>                           m.CustomAttributes.Where(a => a.AttributeType == typeOfRequest).Count()>0
>                        )
>                        ||
>                        (  typeOfRequest == typeof(HttpGetAttribute) &&
>                           m.CustomAttributes.Where(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(HttpPostAttribute)).Count() == 0
>                        )
>                     )
>                 );
>             MethodInfo actionMethodInfo = actionMethodInfo = cntMethods != null && cntMethods.Count() == 1 ? cntMethods.ElementAt(0):null;
> ```

Reference : https://techatfingers.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/session-state-on-action/

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you have two action with the same name, but one is for "Get", other is for "Post" , You could try out the **[HttpGet]** to the first action and **[HttpPost]** to the section action or you can try something like this if your action serves requests from multiple verbs

```
[HttpGet, HttpPost] or [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

For Example , 
if your function name is GetMethod then try like this

```
[HttpGet]
Public ActionResult GetMethod()
{
   //do something ...
}

[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult GetMethod()
{
   //do something ...
}
```

Comment: I know how to add annotation to my same name action, but I do not know how to make the method " controllerType.GetMethod(actionName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)" distinguish which method the exception happend. The "get one" or the "post one".

Answer (score 0):

One approach to solve this issue is to use the `GetMethods()` method on the `System.Type` object to return a list of methods on the `System.Type` object. Use a LINQ query to filter the method list to just those methods that match a specific action name.

Add this approach by replacing the following in your code:

```
var method = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

with the following `if` condition that checks if multiple methods are found that match the variable `actionName` from your code. Define a string variable that identifies the action type (i.e. "HttpGet" or "HttpPost") and compare it to the attributes of each method in the filtered list.

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] matchedMethods = controllerType.GetMethods(
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(m => m.Name == actionName).ToArray<System.Reflection.MethodInfo>();

if (matchedMethods.Length > 1)
{
    string attributeTypeString = "HttpGet"; // Change this to "HttpPut" or the text of any custom attribute filter
    foreach (System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo in matchedMethods)
    {
        if (methodInfo.CustomAttributes.Count() == 0) { continue; }
        // An alternative below is to explicitly check against a defined attribute type (e.g. `ca.AttributeType == ...`).
        if (methodInfo.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(ca => ca.ToString().IndexOf(attributeTypeString) == 0) !=null)
        {
            method = methodInfo;
            break; // Break out of the 'foreach' loop since a match was found
        }
    }
}
else
{
    method = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
}
```

### Code notes

I used strongly-typed variable declarations (versus 'var') so it's easier to follow what the code is doing.

Add `using System.Reflection;` and `using System.Linq` at the top of the class file. I listed the full assembly declaration of a variable/type/flag in the code above so that again it's easier to follow (at least for me) in this answer.

The first line of code in the above solution can be broken into separate lines to make it easier to follow:

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] allMethods = controllerType.GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] matchedMethods = allMethods.Where(m => m.Name == actionName).ToArray<System.Reflection.MethodInfo>();
```

Note the `if` condition within the `foreach` loop.

```
if (methodInfo.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(ca => ca.ToString().IndexOf(attributeTypeString) == 0) !=null)
```

The `if` condition doesn't have to convert the custom attribute to a string. An alternative is to explicitly check against a defined attribute type (e.g. `ca.AttributeType == ...`). If the condition does check against the text of an attribute name then ensure the string comparison method (e.g. `IndexOf()` used here) satisfies the conditions of your application. For example, I used `IndexOf() > -1` to determine if the text of variable `attributeTypeString` is listed anywhere in a custom attribute because I assumed that there should not be another custom attribute that contains the text 'HttpGet'.